# documents disappearing from solution folders in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

A coworker and I have the same intermittent problem with Visual Studio 2008.  We store various documents, like Word docs or Photoshop files in a solution folder. Those files sometimes "disappear" after we edit them using the native app.  The files are still on the hard drive, but the solution seems to have lost its reference to the file.  Any one else run into this or have a fix?

Comment: I seriously doubt this gets put to the test much.  Most programmers use source control.  Doesn't matter much what happens to the file on disk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469695/word-files-disappear-from-solution-items-in-vs2010

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is because VS solution items are 'tracked', so if the file is removed and then re-added, or simply not there at all then the solution will automatically remove it.

It's incredibly annoying, I expect maybe Word is removing the file before saving it, which causes the solution to think it's no longer the same file.

We have this issue with multiple developers if they haven't gotten a file from source control before opening a solution, it just removes the file.